# My input field for google image search isn't working

Tags: html, forms

My image search form doesn't work. when i press submit button it refers me the google image page than i have to search again.do you know what is wrong?Thanks

````
```
<form action="https://www.google.com/imghp?q=" method="GET">
 <input type="text" id="first" name="q">
 <br>
 <br>
 <input class="sub" type="submit" class="sub" value="Image Search" >
 <br>
 </form>
 ```
````

Answer (score 0):

change action to this one :

```
<form method="get" action="http://images.google.com/images">
  <input type="text" name="q" />
  <input type="submit" value="Google Search" />
</form>
```

Comment: In other words, OP should trim the `?q=` part from the form action url.

Comment: do you mean?

"http://images.google.com/?q=" I have tried but still doesnt work

Comment: i think the url is for image search page and not direct search thats why its not working

Comment: i have tried different ones still didnt. should i change anything with my input name attribute?